# email verification not working in socioboard 4.0

Tags: node.js, laravel, gmail, email-validation

I have installed and run SocioBoard successfully 
but when I register as a new user I am not receiving a verification email
I tried Gmail as an SMTP and here is my .env code of Laravel

```
MAIL_DRIVER= smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my@gmail.id
MAIL_PASSWORD=mygmailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and here is node API's config file code

```
"mailService": {
        "defaultMailOption": "gmail",
        "sendgrid": {
            "username": "<<sendgrid username>>",
            "password": "<<sendgrid password>>",
            "frommail": "<<sendgrid frommail>>",
            "ccmail": "<<sendgrid ccmail>>",
            "apiKey": "<<sendgrid apiKey>>"
        },
        "gmailServices": {
            "email": "my@gmail.id",
            "password": "mygmailpassword"
        }
    },
```

is am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Please, keep this node API's config file code in the following file

Notification-> config -> default

Comment: yeah I did that too. even I modified in publish, feeds and user but even I didn't get the verification email.

Comment: Are you using this  **"mail_services_environments": [
       "development"
    ], - env ?**  means it should be "development" NODE_ENV, as of code these are in config of user Microservices and you should use any one of it, If still you not able to get mail, show me the response what you getting.

Comment: Yes i am using `set node_env=development` but still didn't recive. and what kind of responce do i need to show?

Comment: can we disable email verification. so that I can access it directly. and one more thing I tried making an `activation status = 1` from database side and when trying to login I am getting **something is wrong** error, is there any way to access it?

Comment: **2nd one is Correct , (status change)**, But, Have you seeded application information seeder, where package details are available. **login code depends on user details, user activation and application information tables** so check the plan value in user_activation and plan details in application information table

Comment: Thanks @SureshBabu It worked through the database. but if there should be a demo database then that would be more helpful. and email verification issue still exist

Comment: We updated new Code in Git, if you didn't updated please update once, or else check this **sendActivationMail(mail)** function in **user->core->unauthorized->utils->unauthorizedlibs.js** file, and you should keep running all services of node for better response , if still have a problem, After sign-up Please try to display the reply from node-API, you can get clear Idea of it.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall everything or just need to change user->core->unauthorized->utils->unauthorizedlibs.js ?

Comment: **just change it**. and **make sure everything is having their redirection in that file**, If you think much changed in new update, then please do it with new.